# boot2docker shellinit command ended up in error "Error requesting socket: exit status 255"

Tags: sockets, docker, boot2docker

Installed boot2docker on OSX, as per instructions of http://boot2docker.io/. After that started the application. In a terminal, boot2docker shellinit command started and ended up in throwing this error "Error requesting socket: exit status 255". Tried boot2docker stop--->delete--->download--->init--->up . It didn't help. The version I used is v1.3.1. Any ideas why it might have failed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this solution worked for me. It seems like, it is mandatory to have the localhost assigned to 127.0.0.1 in our hosts file(location is /etc/hosts). The following line should be there in /etc/hosts

`127.0.0.1       localhost`

And do the following. At the end, assign variables as the console shows.

`boot2docker init
boot2docker download
boot2docker up`

Answer (score 0):

try to see the actual error in virtualbox screen.

For me it was because visualization was not enabled in my bios.
I could see “this kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detects an i686 CPU, unable to boot” error in virtual box screen

in bios, security>visualization>enable>save and exit

Good luck