# Boot2Docker for OS X fails to start

Tags: macos, docker, virtualbox, boot2docker

I am new to docker and I'm attempting to run boot2docker on my work computer. I'm logged in to the computer running OS X version 10.10.1 (Yosemite) with a user account that mounts the home directory from the office network.

I installed Docker v1.4.1 from https://github.com/boot2docker/osx-installer/releases
and VirtualBox 4.3.20 for OS X hosts from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

I followed the instructions on docker.com mac installation but I didn't get the supposed to be results.

The docker terminal gives this error:

```
bash-3.2$ /usr/local/bin/boot2docker init 
Virtual machine boot2docker-vm already exists
bash-3.2$ /usr/local/bin/boot2docker up 
error in run: Failed to start machine "boot2docker-vm" (run again with -v for details)
bash-3.2$ $(/usr/local/bin/boot2docker shellinit)
error in run: VM "boot2docker-vm" is not running.
bash-3.2$ docker version
Client version: 1.4.1
Client API version: 1.16
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): 5bc2ff8
OS/Arch (client): darwin/amd64
FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.16/version: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

Starting boot2docker-vm on VirtualBox returns the following error:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine boot2docker-vm.

NamedPipe#0 failed to bind to local socket
/Network/Servers/servername/Volumes/cal/Users/username/.boot2docker/boot2docker-vm.sock (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this solution worked for me. I have to move the VirtualBox VMs folder from my network home directory to my local machine and change their permissions.

So on my VirtualBox GUI, under Settings>Storage, I changed the file locations from

```
/Network/Servers/servername/Volumes/cal/Users/username/VirtualBox VMs/boot2docker.iso
/Network/Servers/servername/Volumes/cal/Users/username/VirtualBox VMs/boot2docker-vm/boot2docker-vm.vmdk
```

to

```
/Applications/VirtualBox VMs/boot2docker.iso
/Applications/VirtualBox VMs/boot2docker-vm/boot2docker-vm.vmdk
```

and under the Settings>Ports

from

```
/Network/Servers/servername/Volumes/cal/Users/username/VirtualBox VMs/boot2docker-vm.sock
```

to

```
/Applications/VirtualBox VMs/boot2docker-vm.sock
```

So I think it’s a directory and permission issue.

Answer (score 15):

Try the following:
Some people have reported problems starting suspended boot2docker VM's the steps below have normally fixed the issue for me.

```
boot2docker delete
boot2docker download
boot2docker init
boot2docker up
```

If this does not work Open the Virtual box and see the status of the boot2docker vm. If it says saved, then start the VM from the UI and then send it the shutdown signal from the menu. You should then be able to start and stop the VM from boot2docker subsequently.

Comment: I still get an error 'error in run: Failed to start machine "boot2docker-vm" (run again with -v for details)'

Comment: can you run boot2docker version?

Comment: Yes. The output is 'Boot2Docker-cli version: v1.4.1'

Comment: I suspected you may have this issue: https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker-cli/issues/292 The steps above fixed it for me but maybe there is some other problem. I have added some other suggestions above

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Igor! There are actually many issues on github related to these kinds of behaviors, I found this one to be most informative https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/392

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. I had to reinstall everything from scratch but after that it failed to start. I did the above and it fixed my issue.

Comment: Look at my answer below, I had to run `$(boot2docker shellinit)` after running the 4 commands Usman Ismail gave above. That fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and this series of commands worked for me:

```
boot2docker up
$(boot2docker shellinit)
```

After that, I was able to run commands like `docker ps` and `docker images` without getting an error, so I was all set.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is similar to the problem which I got earlier. It seems like, it is mandatory to have the localhost assigned to 127.0.0.1 in our hosts file(location is /etc/hosts). The following line should be there in /etc/hosts. Hope it helps!! [boot2docker shellinit command ended up in error "Error requesting socket: exit status 255"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738873/boot2docker-shellinit-command-ended-up-in-error-error-requesting-socket-exit-s)

`127.0.0.1       localhost`

P.S: Edited the post because links might be gone

Answer (score 1):

A combination of couple of answers helped me to resolve the issue:

As Usman Ismail said, run the following:

```
boot2docker delete
boot2docker download
boot2docker init
boot2docker up
```

And then run:

```
$(boot2docker shellinit)
```

That worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my experience...

At home I have a Macbook Air, and at work I have a Macbook Pro.

I was having the same issues on both. If I ran from command line, I would get something about "VBOX_E_OBJECT_IN_USE". And if I ran from Virtual Box UI, I would get something about "VMMR0.r0".

I tried almost everything...reinstalling VBX, B2D, etc. To no avail.

**Then finally, on the MBA, I tried Usman's suggestions and that fixed it.**

But that didn't work on my MBP.

**For the MBP, I had to Repair My Disk Permissions with Disk Utility.**

(Thanks to mpwin for the suggestion in this thread: https://github.com/boot2docker/windows-installer/issues/63)

Now, both machines work. Hopefully, this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error if I restart my MBP and allow iTerm2 to start automatically with previous tabs open. I've found that restarting iTerm2 solves it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add your configs to your bash:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/<username>/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```

then open a new terminal window or source the file.